# No such option: -U on Heroku when trying to install discord.py from Git

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, pip, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot and put it on Heroku. My code only uses `discord.py`, that is the only requirement. To install the latest version of `discord.py` locally using `pip` I have to use the command:

```
pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]
```

I have `pip` and `pip3` on my laptop so I have to use `pip3`. This installation works properly on my laptop and I can write code with it that runs perfectly.

If I try to add this line to the `requirements.txt` however Heroku is complaining that there is no `-U` option.

I don't know if this is because I use `pip3` and not `pip`, or because Heroku can't handle installing from a Git repo, or because I'm using wrong syntax for that (most likely) but I couldn't find any way to install this version 1.0.0a of `discord.py` on Heroku.

(Note that `pip install discord` does not work, that would install 0.16 version, even though this is what the `discord.py` tell you to do - installing it from the repo was a solution used by SentDex in his YouTube video about making a discord bot using Python.)

How can I install `discord.py@rewrite` on Heroku?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `-U` flag. That's for upgrading an existing package if it exists, and Heroku won't have a package to upgrade. Try just taking it out. I think just `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]` should work (I also took out a space). If that works I'll add a proper answer.

Comment: It does work, thank you. I didn't know what the -U stands for. Now it installs the package without any problem. The code gave an error though (which did not happen when I was running it locally on my laptop or raspberrypi). It doesn't really matter though, since it looks like I've used up all my attempts, and I have to add a credit card now to be able to access my dyno at all :(.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I just had to use it without the -U, so:

git+https://github.com/Rapptz /discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]

goes in the requirements.txt